# fill a dataGridView with content from an Access db with a relationship

Tags: vb.net

Im having trouble getting the correct data to display in a DataGridView. I have two tables (Student) and (Module) in an access db, I have the text boxes displaying the data from the Student tables but i need the DataGridView to display their corresponding modules. the code is

```
  Public Class frnMain

Dim objConnection As New OleDb.OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0; Data Source = Students.accdb")
Dim objStudentDA As New OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter("Select * From Student", objConnection)
Dim objStudentCB As New OleDb.OleDbCommandBuilder(objStudentDA)
Dim objDataSet As New DataSet()

Dim objModuleDA As New OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter("Select * from Student", objConnection)
Dim objModuleCB As New OleDb.OleDbCommandBuilder(objModuleDA)

Dim Counter As Integer = 1

Private Sub frnMain_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

    Retrieve()
    FillStudentDetails()

End Sub

Public Sub Retrieve()

    objDataSet.Clear()

    objStudentDA.FillSchema(objDataSet, SchemaType.Source, "Student")
    objStudentDA.Fill(objDataSet, "student")

    objModuleDA.FillSchema(objDataSet, SchemaType.Source, "Module")
    objModuleDA.Fill(objDataSet, "Module")

    'Set Relationships
    objDataSet.Relations.Clear()
    objDataSet.Relations.Add("student2Module", objDataSet.Tables("Student").Columns("StudentId"),
                             objDataSet.Tables("Module").Columns("StudentId"))


End Sub


Public Sub FillStudentDetails()

    Dim objrow As DataRow
    Dim objModule As DataRow

    objrow = objDataSet.Tables("Student").Rows.Find(Counter)
    objModule = objDataSet.Tables("Module").Rows.Find(Counter)

    mtbStudentId.Text = objrow.Item("StudentId")
    txtName.Text = objrow.Item("StudentName")
    txtAddress.Text = objrow.Item("StudentAddress")

    For Each objModules In objrow.GetChildRows("Student2Module")
        dgvModule.DataSource = objDataSet.Tables(0)
    Next

End Sub
```

I know the code is wrong in the for loop at the end I was just experimenting to see if i could get it. thanks in advance.

Comment: Your dataadapters execute the same query _select * from student_. Is it a typo?

Comment: I changed it but now im getting IErrorInfo.GetDescription failed with E_FAIL(0x80004005). at the ModuleDA.FillSchema, thanks for spotting it though

Comment: Do you have an exception? If yes what is the exception Message property and if there is an InnerException what is the message of the InnerException?

Comment: this is the exception: An unhandled exception of type 'System.Data.OleDb.OleDbException' occurred in System.Data.dll

Additional information: IErrorInfo.GetDescription failed with E_FAIL(0x80004005).

Comment: I was googling it and all I found was its caused by a sql reserved keyword

Comment: it occurs on the line         'objModuleDA.FillSchema(objDataSet, SchemaType.Source, "Module")'

Comment: Yes, Module is a reserved keyword for MS-Access, write your query as _select * from [Module]_ (Just the query, not the other parts of your code where you use Module to refer to the table name inside the dataset)

Comment: perfect thanks it is now running but it is still putting the data from the student table into the DataGridView instead of the module Table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed it by using fixed columns and just looping through the other table

```
 dgvModule.ColumnCount = 3
    dgvModule.Columns(0).Name = "Module ID"
    dgvModule.Columns(1).Name = "Module Name"
    dgvModule.Columns(2).Name = "Student Id "



    dgvModule.Rows.Clear()
    For i As Integer = 1 To objDataSet.Tables("Module").Rows.Count
        objModule = objDataSet.Tables("Module").Rows.Find(i)

        If currentId = objModule.Item("StudentId") Then
            Dim row As String() = New String() {(objModule.Item("ModuleId")), objModule.Item("ModuleName"), objModule.Item("StudentId")}
            dgvModule.Rows.Add(row)
        Else

        End If


    Next
```